# Face API face CORS error. Someone solve it pls

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, cors

I'm quite new of using API and here.

I'm facing CORS prob.

Error is below .

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect?api_key={0}&api_secret={1}&image_url={2}&return_attributes={3}' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3111' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
;
```

And here is my code

```js
        async submit(){
          let imgSrc = document.getElementById("photo").src        
          const self = this
          try{
            let headers = {headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",}}
            console.log(headers)
            let response = await self.$axios.$post(CONSTANTS.API_URL,self.createParam(imgSrc),headers)
            console.log(response)
          }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
          }
        },
```

I could check this API works properly at Restlet Client on Google Chrome.

[this is screen shot on Restlet Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAtv4.png)

Help me somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set on the server, not on the client.

Are you sending your request from localhost and does the API accept calls from localhost?

More information about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Mr.allard thx for comment. Yes, I send requst from localhost

Answer (score 0):

Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not the one in the ajax request nor in the ajax response. The error is telling you that the script is attempting to download a resource from an untrust origin.

The origin here is the one from where the script is downloaded. So the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` need to be set by your backend that serve you the script containing the submit.

Comment: Mr.mathk  thx for answer . I didn't know server allow Access from localhost . I'll check it out.